# How do i delete the last row from a separate excel sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button that is on sheet2 and i am trying to delete the last row in sheet1 using VBA.

When i delete the row, i dont want my screen to go to sheet1.

This was happening when i tried to use .activate.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete


End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `ActiveSheet` with `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`, or use the sheet's codename, most likely `Sheet1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name of the first sheet is *Sheet1* then use:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete
```